# sqlalchemy.exc.DataError while executing the update query in Postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to write a simple flask application where I am using a Postgresql as database. I am trying to update the table row on button click but it is giving me following error

> DataError: (psycopg2.DataError) invalid input syntax for integer: "125/" LINE 1: ...ATE tasks SET taskname='IamUpdated' WHERE tasks.uid = '125/' ^ [SQL: 'UPDATE tasks SET taskname=%(taskname)s WHERE tasks.uid = %(uid_1)s'] [parameters: {'taskname': 'IamUpdated', 'uid_1': u'125/'}]

I am not sure if it is adding "/" at the end as a glitch or it is supposed to be like that? or That is what causing an error.
Please Help.

Following is my Flask Python code

```
edituser = request.form.getlist('editId')
        if edituser:
            for e in edituser:
                User.query.filter_by(uid=e).update(dict(taskname="IamUpdated"))
            db.session.commit()
            return render_template("index.html",User=User.query.all())
```

Following is my HTML code

```
<form action="" method="POST">

    <div ng-controller="myctrl" >

     <table>
        <caption> Todo List</caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="text">
                        <input type="submit"  value="Add Task" >

                    </td><td>
                    Search :<input type="text"> 

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Task Id</th>
                    <th>Task</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

                {% for user in User %}
                <tr>
                    <td> {{ user.uid }} </td>
                    <td >{{ user.taskname }} 
                        <input type="image" class="deleteImg" src="static/img/trash_can.png" height="15px" width="18px" name="removeId" value={{user.uid}} /> 
                         <input type="image" src="static/img/editbtn.svg"  height="15px" width="18px" name="editId" value={{user.uid}}/>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script>

    var app = angular.module("app", ['xeditable']);
    app.controller('myctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myname="Howdy";       
    });
    app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//').endSymbol('//');
    });

    app.run(function(editableOptions) {
        editableOptions.theme = 'bs3'; // bootstrap3 theme. Can be also 'bs2', 'default'
    });
    </script>  
 </form> 
</body>
```

Comment: We need to see where editId is coming from. I suspect you have an error in your template.

Comment: @shadow please check I added HTML code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be this tag here:

```
<input type="image" src="static/img/editbtn.svg"  height="15px" width="18px" name="editId" value={{user.uid}}/>
```

All values in html are strings. Therefore they must all be quoted.

```
value="{{user.uid}}"
```

Once you've done this, HTML will know exactly what you meant to include in the value, rather than guessing.

The reason this hasn't affected other fields is because this is the only time you didn't put a space between the value and the number.

Answer (score 0):

The error was because I have "/>" at the end of the input tag. it was unnecessary. I have removed it and now it is working fine.

Comment: This would technically work - but it doesn't address the real problem you have - namely, not quoting your value. Please see my answer for more details.